# How to create two separate foreign key columns in two different tables with the same name in a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, foreign-keys, key

I wrote this code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[USERS]
(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [First_Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Last_Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [email] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Password] [text] NOT NULL,
    [User_Type] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Date_of_Birth] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Gender] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Login_with] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Phone] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Receive_Coupon] [int] NULL,
    [Country_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Created] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Modified] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Status] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Language_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Country_ID FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES COUNTRIES,
    CONSTRAINT Language_ID FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES LANGUAGE,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_USERS] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

But I got this error

[image: Error]

Except changing name of `Country_ID` column, how can I fix this error?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLylp.png)

Comment: You will only cause MORE confusion by naming a constraint in a manner that suggests a column. And DON'T use the text datatype - deprecated many many years ago. In addition, you need to research and implement proper security practices. You should NEVER store a plain-text password. In fact, there are more than a few security / PII issues to be addressed here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm **assuming** you want to establish foreign key constraints between:

- `dbo.Users.Country_Id` and `dbo.Countries.Id`
- `dbo.Users.Language_Id` and `dbo.Language.Id`

but you're not doing that right now - instead, use this syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[USERS]
(
    -- all your columns here
    CONSTRAINT FK_Users_Countries 
        FOREIGN KEY (Country_ID) REFERENCES dbo.Countries(ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Users_Language
        FOREIGN KEY (Language_ID) REFERENCES dbo.Language(Id),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_USERS] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
)
```

You need to

- give your FK constraint a name (e.g. `FK_Users_Countries`)
- then define what column in your current table (`dbo.Users`) is the foreign key column (e.g. `Country_Id` - in the `FOREIGN KEY (column)` part)
- and then define what it references - typically the table and the column in that table (after the `REFERENCES` keyword)

Your current code:

```
CONSTRAINT Country_ID FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES COUNTRIES,
```

is defining a foreign key constraint called `Country_ID`, which was matching the `dbo.Users.ID` column to the primary key of the `Countries` table. Most likely, you already have another table that has the same, wrong line of code and thus already defined a constraint called `Country_ID` - and you just **cannot** have two database objects with an identical name - no workaround here....